# Nginx. If Empty URI. If Empty Domain. Location. Regex

Tags: nginx, location

I'm using the upstream module for balancing my site. For some reason i have to redirect some requests to a specified server.
So in short: i want to redirect domain.com to a specified server, domain.com/anything can be served by the upstream module. So if theres only the domain in the request and nothing else.

```
   location [here_something_i_dont_know]/ {
        proxy_pass           http://0.0.0.0:9000/;
        access_log      off;
    }
```

Thanks for ur help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   location = / {
        proxy_pass           http://0.0.0.0:9000/;
        access_log      off;
   }
   location / {
        proxy_pass           http://another_upstream;
        access_log      off;
   }
```